# Not able to parse multiline array in powershell

Tags: powershell

My aws cli returns multiline array with nested hash, I am not able to parse output to get appropriate values from it

```
>Write-Host $a
[
  [
     [
         {
             "VolumeID": "vol-fxxxxxx"
         }
     ]
   ]
]
```

If I do $a[0], it returns first line i.e. "[" same with incremental indexs.
How I can parse this array and get the volumeID from it ?
Thanks

Additional details :

Thanks for your valuable answers. Here is the class name of the above object :

```
> $a.getType()                                                                                                          
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                             
 -------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                             
True     True     Object[]                               System.Array

> $a | Where-Object ($_ -like "*Volume*")

> $a | ConvertFrom-Json
 ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: 
 Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData.
 At line:1 char:6


 + $a | ConvertFrom-Json
 +      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

Hi Martin Brandl, TessellatingHeckler I have updated with your question, could you please help me out on the same.
Thanks

Comment: can you post the output of `$a.GetType()`

Comment: Could it be that `$a` is just a multiline string, and `$a[0]` returns `[` because that's the first character?

Answer (score 2):

> same with incremental indexs

I can't make sense of incremental indexes doing the *same*, and returning the first line, but it looks like it's either:

A multiline string (`$a.gettype()` has `Name: String`):

```
$b = $a | ConvertFrom-Json
$b[0][0][0].VolumeID
```

or, an array of string (`$a.gettype() Name is Object[] or String[]`), do this first, then convert from JSON:

```
$a = -join $a
```

Comment: `$b[0].VolumeID` seems to suffice, despite the nested arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the where-object cmdlet.

```
$a | where-object {$_ -like "*Volume*"}
```

More information on the where-object cmdlet can be found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx

Thanks, Tim.